# friend selector when using Feed Dialog

Tags: user-interface, facebook-wall, facebook-canvas

I know I can use the Feed Dialog to post to a friend's wall by sending/using the "to" parameter... as well documented in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I wonder if is it possible to say the Feed Dialog to show a friend selector widget/type ahead combo (as the Send Dialog does) or some thing to select the user whose he is looking... ?

Any idea.

Thanks in advance